# Request for reference: uniform convergence for non 0-1 loss functions

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, machine-learning

In the book "Understanding machine learning", there is Theorem 6.11 with the following statement

> Let ${\cal H}$ be a class and let $\tau_{\cal H}$ be its growth function. Then, for every $\cal D$ and every $\delta \in (0, 1)$, with probability at least $1-\delta$ over the choice $S \sim {\cal D}^m$ we have
> $$
> |L_{\cal D}(h) - L_S(h)| \leq \frac{4 + \sqrt{\log{\tau_{\cal H}(2m)}}}{\delta \sqrt{2m}}.
> $$

The theorem shows the uniform convergence property, though one can see that the proof utilizes the fact that the considered loss function is 0-1 loss. Where to read the similar proofs for other loss functions (say, for hinge loss)?

Comment: Have you read the paper [Learnability, Stability and Uniform Convergence](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/shalev-shwartz10a/shalev-shwartz10a.pdf) coauthored by one of the authors of that book?  I have only skimmed it myself, but it seems like it may have what you are looking for.

Comment: @Joe, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Do you recommend the book "Understanding Machine Learning"? I don't have that one.